# Reading and writing a file bit by bit in c++

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

I am trying to read and write a binary file bit by bit. I use the following code to read bits:

```
this->infile.open(this->inFileAdd,ios::binary|ios::in|ios::ate);

    this->size=infile.tellg();

    infile.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    fileContent=new bitset<8>[size];
    char c;
    int i=0;
    while (infile.get(c))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            fileContent[i][j]=((c >> j) & 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    infile.close();
```

and I use the following code to write the same contents to another file:

```
string fsave="D:\\a.jpg";
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(fsave,ios::binary|ios::out);
    for (int i=0;i<steg.size;i++) {
        char c;
        cout<<i<<")";
        for (int var = 0; var < 8; ++var) {
            c|= steg.fileContent[i][var] << var;
            cout<<steg.fileContent[i][var];
        }
        outfile.write(&c,sizeof(c));
        cout<<endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
```

But interestingly when I use the following Unix command to compare the source and destination files they are not the same:

```
cmp -l "001-Copy.jpg" "a.jpg" | wc -l
```

Comment: Should char c be initialized in the write section?

Comment: undefined behavior, because here `c|= steg.fileContent[i][var] << var;` you didn't initialize `c`

Comment: @Vasilij : Oh, Thank you so much. It fixed my problem. I don't know why didn't I initialize it!

Comment: What is the requirement to read with bitset<8> instead of char or unsigned char?

Comment: See if using uchar fixes it.

Comment: @Klaus  It's somehow a necessity of the project.

Comment: A technical solution is not a requirement. So I want to use *why* you read it by bitset not that someone has decided it :-)